# Bouncy Castle Library Support to Switch from AES_CBC to AES_CFB encryption

Tags: android, encryption, bouncycastle, cbc-mode, cfb-mode

I am using one library which encrypts the data using bouncy castle library in android project which used AES_CFB encryption mode. Earlier this library was using CBC and in my android application I was able to decrypt the key by using below code.

```
 private fun getPrivateKey(certObject: PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo, keyPassPhrase: String): PrivateKey? {
        val bouncyCastleProvider = BouncyCastleProvider()
        val decryptionProvider: InputDecryptorProvider =
            JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().setProvider(bouncyCastleProvider)
                .build(keyPassPhrase.toCharArray())
        val info = certObject.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(decryptionProvider)
        val converter = JcaPEMKeyConverter()
        return converter.getPrivateKey(info)
    }
```

Now that library has changed the encryption mode to AES_CFB. So the above code is giving the below exception while decrypting it on this line

```
val info = certObject.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(decryptionProvider)
```

Exception:

```
Method threw 'org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException' exception.

unable to read encrypted data: no key size for algorithm:2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.44
```

Can someone help in how to switch from CBC to CFB using bouncy castle?

Adding Sample code here

```
public class Application {   
 

private final static String passphrase = "password";


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      BouncyCastleProvider securityProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
     
      Security.addProvider(securityProvider);
      PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedPrivateKeyInfo = getPrivateKeyInfo();
      System.out.println("Private key algorithm encrypted: " + encryptedPrivateKeyInfo.getEncryptionAlgorithm().getAlgorithm());
      InputDecryptorProvider decryptionProvider = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder()
              .setProvider(securityProvider)
              .build(passphrase.toCharArray());
      PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = encryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(decryptionProvider);
      System.out.println("Private key algorithm decrypted: " + privateKeyInfo.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm().getAlgorithm());
    }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }   }

  private static PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo getPrivateKeyInfo() throws IOException {     
    InputStream privateKeyInputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/key.k8");
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(privateKeyInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Object pemObject = pemParser.readObject();
    return (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) pemObject;  
 

} 
}
```

And the src/main/resources/key.k8 file contains

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- 
<private key encrypted with AES_CFB_256 encryption using bouncy castle>
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: *...which encrypts the data...*: Are you aware that the posted code decrypts an *encrypted PKCS#8 key*? *...I am using one library which...* Can you say more about this library, e.g. post the encryption code (the old one that uses CBC and the new one that is supposed to use CFB)? Can you share a **non-productive** encrypted sample key and password?

Comment: Yes the posted code works with CBC encryption mode. The library is not exposed with me. only I know is that the library now uses CFB instead of CBC. I just want to convert this code to decrypt the data using CFB mode using bouncy castle. Can you please tell me how can we use bouncy castle to decrypt using AES_CFB mode

Comment: As already mentioned, the posted code decrypts an encrypted PKCS#8 key. There is more involved than just AES (with CBC or CFB), namely a password-based key derivation. If your BouncyCastle based code can't decrypt the key, that's an indication of some outdated/rare/non-standard logic. Therefore, to learn more about this logic, the encryption code is needed or at least (non-productive) sample data (encrypted PKCS#8 key including password).